# How to label dots on an axis? Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can I add dots to the x-axis like the ones between 2020 - 2024? How to do that?

The results_df has dates as index and some columns of slopes.

## Plot the slope with crisis periods

```
    slope_fig, slope_ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 8))  # Increased figure size for better clarity
    results_df.filter(like='Slope').plot(ax=slope_ax, title=f'{title} Slope')
    for crisis, start, end in crisis_periods:
        slope_ax.axvspan(start, end, color='grey', alpha=0.3)
        slope_ax.text(start, slope_ax.get_ylim()[1], crisis, rotation=90, verticalalignment='top')
    slope_ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))  # Move legend outside of the plot
    slope_ax.set_ylabel('Slope')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-scatter) with `clip_on` set to `False`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

slope_fig, slope_ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 8))  # Increased figure size for better clarity
crisis_periods = [('big crisis', 2007, 2010), ('end of the world', 2012, 2013), ('yet another crisis', 2015, 2016)]
for crisis, start, end in crisis_periods:
    slope_ax.axvspan(start, end, color='grey', alpha=0.3)
    slope_ax.text(start, slope_ax.get_ylim()[1], crisis, rotation=90, verticalalignment='top')

slope_ax.set_ylabel('Slope')
y_min, y_max = slope_ax.get_ylim()
crisis_moments = [2008, 2009]
# place moment points on the x-axis
slope_ax.scatter(crisis_moments, [y_min]*len(crisis_moments), color='blue', clip_on=False)
# enforce the original y-limits
slope_ax.set_ylim(y_min, y_max)
plt.show()
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to automatically insert dots on January 1st of each year, without having to specify the exact locations?

Comment: Not that I know of it. A matplotlib scatter plot always needs both x and y data positions. But it's pretty easy to generate a range of beginning dates of each year between specified start and end dates, e.g. like this: `pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq="YS")`, where `start_date` and `end_date` are taken from your original dataset `results_df`.